# Manifest giving error when using route with params

Tags: reactjs

The error I get is this:

```
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

However, this only happens for a specific component.
In app.js I have declared a few routes. This way:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <main>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/test" exact>
                    <Test />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/activate/:activationString">
                    <Activate />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

When browsing to "/" or even to "/test", the console does not show any error.
As soon as I go to

```
/activate/randomString
```

then the error shows up in the console. To me it is quite obvious that it depends on the fact that the route with the error differs from the other as it includes params. Or at least this is the only difference I can see. Because the component itself (Activate) contains for example exactly the some code (it is just printing some text):

```
import React from 'react';
const Activate = () => {
return(
    <>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col s6 m6 offset-s3 offset-m3 center marginTop60">
                Activate
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);
}
export default Activate;
```

If I modify the route and remove the params, i.e. just having:

```
<Route path="/activate">
```

The the error does not show up. So I wonder if I need to add some directive in manifest.json maybe? But could not find anything about that.

---

Adding manifest.json

```
{
"short_name": "React App",
"name": "Create React App Sample",
"icons": [
{
  "src": "favicon.ico",
  "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
  "type": "image/x-icon"
},
{
  "src": "logo192.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "192x192"
},
{
  "src": "logo512.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "512x512"
}
],
"start_url": ".",
"display": "standalone",
"theme_color": "#000000",
"background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

And this is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link crossorigin="use-credentials" rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show us `manifest.json`?

Comment: I added the content of manifest.json in the question.

Comment: can you add `public/index.html`?

Comment: Added that too. Its the standard index.html generated by reacy-create-app with no modification added by me.

Comment: I don't find any problems in your code, please create new app with `create-react-app` and check, its still exists?